# python: Flask: deal with Apache's workers/global variable?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

My Flask app updates data using outer service. Results are stored in DB (connected via SQLAlchemy). Code which handles this is (more less) as follows:

```
# if new results appear

# remove past results

db_session.query(MyModel.SimpleData).\
    filter(MyModel.SimpleData.data_state == u'past').delete()

# present values become past

all_present_entries = db_session.query(MyModel.SimpleData).\
    filter(MyModel.SimpleData.data_state == u'present').all()

for present_entry in all_present_entries:

    present_entry.data_state = u'past'

# new values become present

for new_value in new_values:

    db_session.add(MyModel.SimpleData(data_value=new_value,
                            data_state='present'))

# commit if everything is fine

db_session.commit()

db_session.close_all()
```

The problem is that app doesn't pass stress test. When there are more than one worker (within Apache) data become inconsistent. Sometimes past data is empty, SQLAlchemy exceptions appear in logs. Probably solution is to run only one instance of update function amongst Apache's workers.

How to achive this? (set global flag so only one worker at the time runs update function, so other don't overwrite data)

EDIT: 
To be more specific - if I have 5 workers and in a case when there are many requests, I would like that update function is run only by one worker. At the present moment (from the logs) I notice that every worker run update function. It happens because I don't know how to indicate (set global variable?) that update already in progress [triggered by one worker] so other workers shouldn't run update function part.

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. Where are the global variables here?

Comment: How your `inconsistent` data looks like?

Comment: Daniel: not sure if this work this way, but I am looking for "global" variable which is shared amongst all Apache's workers (so only can run update function at the same time)
Jimilian: mainly there are no past entires

Comment: I think you can fix this by working on the database design. SQL is designed for exactly this type of thing. In the mean time what you need is a distributed lock in something like Redis. The problem is your requests will block until they get the lock probably causing more problems.